# Vue.js access value of key

Tags: vue.js

Trying to access the value of the key with Vue.js which is new for me. I want to use the key as the id and access the title with `key.title` or something similar if possible. Here is the code I am trying:

**HTML**

```
  <ul id="all">
    <li v-for="(song,key) in songs" :class="{ active: song.isActive }" v-bind:id="key">
      {{ key.title }} //Hound Dog
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#all',
  data: {
    songs: [
      a:{
        title:'Hound Dog',
        lyrics:'You aint nothing but a hound dog, crying all the time',
        isActive: true 
      },
      b:{
        title:'Long Gone',
        lyrics:'I am long gone today',
        isActive: false
      } 
    ]    
  }
})
```

Comment: `songs` is not a valid javascript object. Does it really have `a:` and `b:` in it? Either you want an object with a and b as properties or an array of song objects.

Comment: Is there an example you could share? I think my goal is pretty clear but I am not as JS savvy as I'd like to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, your `songs` object is not a valid javascript object. I converted it into an array for the purposes of this example. What you call a `key` in this case is just the index of the item in the array and it is just a number, it doesn't have any properties.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#all',
  data: {
    songs: [
      {
        title:'Hound Dog',
        lyrics:'You aint nothing but a hound dog, crying all the time',
        isActive: true 
      },
      {
        title:'Long Gone',
        lyrics:'I am long gone today',
        isActive: false
      } 
    ]    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
  <ul id="all">
    <li v-for="(song, index) in songs" :class="{ active: song.isActive }" v-bind:id="index">
      {{ song.title }} 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

In this second example, I converted songs into an object.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#all',
  data: {
    songs: {
      a: {
        title: 'Hound Dog',
        lyrics: 'You aint nothing but a hound dog, crying all the time',
        isActive: true
      },
      b: {
        title: 'Long Gone',
        lyrics: 'I am long gone today',
        isActive: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<ul id="all">
  <li v-for="(song, key) in songs" :class="{ active: song.isActive }" v-bind:id="key">
    {{ song.title }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Each song has an id. How would I select a song by id to modify, say the title?

Comment: @TripleC Is it part of the data structure or is the `id` what you were calling `a`, `b`?

Comment: The id is what I was calling a or b.

Comment: @TripleC Added the second example. Basically instead of `[ a:{...}]`, it should be `{a:{...}}`.